# Why thread creation is so fast?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

I read in books that thread creation is expensive (not so expensive like process creation but nevertheless it is) and we should avoid it. I write the test code and I was shocked how fast thread creation is.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int testVal = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int ThreadsCount = 10000;
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsCount; i++)
            {
                var myThread = new Thread(MainVoid);
                myThread.Start();
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Test value ={0}", testVal);
            Console.WriteLine("Ended in {0} miliseconds", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} miliseconds per thread ", (double)watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / ThreadsCount);
        }

        static void MainVoid()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref testVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test value =10000

Ended in 702 miliseconds

0,0702 miliseconds per thread.
```

Is my code wrong or thread creation is so fast and advices in books are wrong? (I see only some extra memory consumption per thread but no creation time.)

Comment: Your threads aren't doing any work, are you sure they're actually getting started?

Comment: @blueberryfields Interlocked.Increment(ref testVal); that is work!

Comment: You created 10000 threads in 0.7 seconds - that can be fast or it can be very slow, depending on your task. If you can solve the same task in 0.1 seconds without using any threads, then the threads are slow and don't make any sense. Otherwise, threads are good. Basically, it depends. Thread creation does have an overhead, whether or not you can afford it is the real issue. 0.07 milliseconds per thread can be a lot if you can do the same thing faster without creating a thread. Context matters.

Comment: You haven't actually waited for those threads to start. Also: note - each thread allcates a stack - you will quickly OOM doing this. You may want to consider using the threadpool instead

Comment: @Marc: his output indicates that the threads do start and perform the work. But that's probably just his good luck. His test *could* finish without the threads actually doing anything.

Comment: A processor core can easily execute 5 billion instructions in a second, assuming you don't have an i7 extreme.  So by your measurement, creating and starting a thread costs 350,000 instructions.  That's not a low number.

Comment: Try starting all threads, then joining all of them. That should give a more realistic scenario because you are guaranteed to measure *all* overheads associated with startup and shutdown. And reduce the number of threads a bit to maybe 100 or 1000 because at 10k you will also stress the memory subsystem a lot which you do not want to include in the measurement.

Comment: Just as a week is a long time in politics, 0.07ms can be a long time in performance-critical code.

Answer (score 2):

Thread creation is pretty slow. Consider this bit of code that contrasts the speed of doing things inline, and doing things with multiple threads:

```
private void DoStuff()
{
    const int ThreadsCount = 10000;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int testVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsCount; ++i)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref testVal);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    testVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsCount; ++i)
    {
        var myThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref testVal);
        });
        myThread.Start();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

On my system, doing it inline requires 200 ticks. With threads it's almost 2 million ticks. So using threads here takes approximately 10,000 times as long. I used `ElapsedTicks` here rather than `ElapsedMilliseconds` because with `ElapsedMilliseconds` the output for the inline code was 0. The threads version takes around 700 milliseconds. Context switches are expensive.

In addition, your test is fundamentally flawed because you don't explicitly wait for all of the threads to finish before harvesting the result. It's quite possible that you could output the value of `testVal` before the last thread finishes incrementing it.

When timing code, by the way, you should be sure to run it in release mode without the debugger attached. In Visual Studio, use Ctrl+F5 (start without debugging).

Comment: You didn't actually start any threads, shouldn't there be a `myThread.Start()` in the second for loop?

Comment: @sthotakura: You're right! That was embarrassing. I corrected the code and the description.